# WEB API hangs after leaving ApiController method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My application has been built with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API. But I have a strange issue to share.

The corresponding code is below

```
public class MachinesController : ApiController
{
    private GWData db = new GWData();

    // GET api/Machines/5
    public Machine GetMachine(int id)
    {
        Machine machine = db.Machines.Single(m => m.Id == id);
        if (machine == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return machine;
    }
```

Using following URL, I can examine my API Get method of a controller in Web API.

```
 http://localhost/myweb/api/machines/1
```

And it worked but trying

```
 http://localhost/myweb/api/machines/2
```

makes Web API hangs forever while memory usage of w3wp.exe keeps going up. So I had to eventually kill the w3wp.exe process. Further by making breakpoint inside of the GET method, I made sure that the hanging happens after getting right data and leaving the method.

How can I approach this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've found this cause earlier. This was a problem in serialization of Json. It took forever to serialize navigation properties of an entity if it has many related records. Of course, it was my fault to forget to disable lazy loading. Adding following code solved the problem.

```
public MachinesController()
{
    db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your solution is correct. Instead you may want to have a model to view model structure, where view model object is flat and exposes only the properties you want to:

```
class Order
{
    // properties you want to expose

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    // navigation and other properties you don't want to expose

    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }
}

class OrderViewModel
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

The easiest way to create one from another is to use AutoMapper.

Comment: I would agree with you but I am not sure "correct" is a right word. Since my project is time-essential, and this entity is not critical in this system, I just used raw entity rather than making a model to get the data. Anyway, thanks for sharing the information.